# caffeine how to work it

Tags: power

I just installed Elementary Loki
How do I get caffeine to work?

It does not show up.  If I run it from the term.. I get 
PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk, GLib

Comment: What version of elementary are you using?

Comment: Can you tell us what steps you followed in installing caffeine? And what version you installed. Also, I noticed some tray icons don't show up right in Loki. Maybe it's running in the background? Try to have a look at the running processes.

Comment: Here's the launchpad page for caffeine binaries intended for ubuntu xenial (16.04), can you check you have all the listed dependencies installed and up to date? https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/caffeine

Comment: I checked and the last two were not installed... python-setuptools
python3-all   I get this error if run from term  :~$ caffeine
/usr/bin/caffeine:25: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk, GLib

Comment: I found the answer.. added ppa answer is below  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.  I needed to add the ppa for caffeine

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caffeine-developers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
```

That seemed to do the trick.  Now I have caffeine indicator.  Works well.